Extracting the last element from an json array in SQL
In SQL I have a table with Columns(ID,Ticket,Description,Date) and description column has JSON Array like below
 [{  "Name": "test1"},{  "Name": "test2"},{  "Name": "test3"}]

(Note: There can be any number of array elements. It is not fixed)
How to retrieve only the last array element from the above array in sql.
I want only test3 as description in my final result table.
I have tried many ways but not able to get the last value.
please suggest

@Rakesh Have you tried that in SQL Server?

JSON formally doesn't have a concept of first or last elements, and parsers are allowed to re-order inputs if they find it convenient. Indeed, some parsers will use a dictionary construct that may end up ordering things by the key.

"I have tried many ways ..."  Where???  We do not see a query.

You may parse and order the JSON content with OPENJSON() and default schema. The result is a table with columns key, value and type. The key is an nvarchar(4000) column and when the content is JSON array it holds the index of the element in this array:
SELECT d.ID, d.Ticket, j.Description, d.Date
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 [value] AS Description
  FROM OPENJSON(d.Description)
  ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]) DESC
) j  


Hello Also we can find the last element from a JSON array by using JSON_VALUE which extracts a scalar value (string, number) from a JSON string based on a specified JSON path:
CREATE TABLE Tickets (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Ticket VARCHAR(100),
    Description NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Date DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO Tickets (ID, Ticket, Description, Date)
VALUES 
(1, 'T001', '[{"Name": "test1"}, {"Name": "test2"}, {"Name": "test3"}]', GETDATE());

SELECT 
    ID,
    Ticket, 
    JSON_VALUE((SELECT TOP 1 [value] 
                FROM OPENJSON(Description) 
                ORDER BY [key] desc ), '$.Name') AS LastDescription, date
FROM 
    Tickets;

Hope it helps.

In SQL server you can use OPNEJSON() to parse JSON array from the Description column. it will retrieve the last element in the array based on the index.
Here is an example:
WITH JsonData AS (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        Ticket, 
        Description,
        Date,
        JSON_VALUE(Description, '$[JSON_LENGTH(Description) - 1].Name') AS LastElement
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT ID, Ticket, LastElement AS Description, Date
FROM JsonData;

JSON_VALUE(Description, '$[JSON_LENGTH(Description) - 1].Name'), JSON_LENGTH calculates the last element of the json array. $[JSON_LENGTH(Description) - 1].Name this retrieves the last element in the JSON array by accessing the last index.
Here are some examples and outputs.
1. From your example:
[{ "Name": "test1" }, { "Name": "test2" }, { "Name": "test3" }]

Output:



ID
Ticket
Description
Date




1
123
test3
2024-05-01



2. With Ten elements
[{ "Name": "item1" }, { "Name": "item2" }, { "Name": "item3" }, { "Name": "item4" }, { "Name": "item5" },
 { "Name": "item6" }, { "Name": "item7" }, { "Name": "item8" }, { "Name": "item9" }, { "Name": "item10" }]

Output:



ID
Ticket
Description
Date




10
132
end
2024-05-10



